# Is there a way I can read the JSON file saved by dataframe.to_json(orient='table')?

Tags: python, json, pandas

I updated to pandas 0.20.1 recently and I tried to use the new feature of to_json(orient='table')

```
import pandas as pd
pd.__version__
# '0.20.1'

a = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[4,5,6]})
a.to_json('a.json', orient='table')
```

But how can I read this JSON file to DataFrame?

I tried `pd.read_json('a.json', orient='table')` but it raised `ValueError`

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-7527b25107ef> in <module>()
----> 1 pd.read_json('a.json', orient='table')

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\json.py in read_json(path_or_buf, orient, typ, dtype, convert_axes, convert_dates, keep_default_dates, numpy, precise_float, date_unit, encoding, lines)
    352         obj = FrameParser(json, orient, dtype, convert_axes, convert_dates,
    353                           keep_default_dates, numpy, precise_float,
--> 354                           date_unit).parse()
    355 
    356     if typ == 'series' or obj is None:

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\json.py in parse(self)
    420 
    421         else:
--> 422             self._parse_no_numpy()
    423 
    424         if self.obj is None:

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\json.py in _parse_no_numpy(self)
    650         else:
    651             self.obj = DataFrame(
--> 652                 loads(json, precise_float=self.precise_float), dtype=None)
    653 
    654     def _process_converter(self, f, filt=None):

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __init__(self, data, index, columns, dtype, copy)
    273                                  dtype=dtype, copy=copy)
    274         elif isinstance(data, dict):
--> 275             mgr = self._init_dict(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
    276         elif isinstance(data, ma.MaskedArray):
    277             import numpy.ma.mrecords as mrecords

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _init_dict(self, data, index, columns, dtype)
    409             arrays = [data[k] for k in keys]
    410 
--> 411         return _arrays_to_mgr(arrays, data_names, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
    412 
    413     def _init_ndarray(self, values, index, columns, dtype=None, copy=False):

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _arrays_to_mgr(arrays, arr_names, index, columns, dtype)
   5592     # figure out the index, if necessary
   5593     if index is None:
-> 5594         index = extract_index(arrays)
   5595     else:
   5596         index = _ensure_index(index)

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in extract_index(data)
   5643 
   5644             if have_dicts:
-> 5645                 raise ValueError('Mixing dicts with non-Series may lead to '
   5646                                  'ambiguous ordering.')
   5647 

ValueError: Mixing dicts with non-Series may lead to ambiguous ordering.
```

So is there a way i can read that JSON file? Thanks in advance.

PS: the JSON file looks like this:

```
{"schema": {"pandas_version":"0.20.0","fields":[{"type":"integer","name":"index"},{"type":"integer","name":"a"},{"type":"integer","name":"b"}],"primaryKey":["index"]}, "data": [{"index":0,"a":1,"b":4},{"index":1,"a":2,"b":5},{"index":2,"a":3,"b":6}]}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently the new method outputs some metadata with the dataset into json such as the pandas version. Hence, consider using the built-in `json` module to read in this nested object to extract the value at *data* key:

```
import json
...
with open('a.json', 'r') as f:   
    json_obj = json.loads(f.read())
    df = pd.DataFrame(json_obj['data']).set_index('index')
    df.index.name = None

print(df)          
#    a  b
# 0  1  4
# 1  2  5
# 2  3  6
```

---

Should you intend to use *type* and *name*, run dictionary and list comprehension on those parts in nested json. Though here, *integer* has to be sliced to *int*. The *dtype* argument cannot be used since names are not saved until after the step:

```
with open('a.json', 'r') as f:   
    json_obj = json.loads(f.read())
    df = pd.DataFrame(json_obj['data'], columns=[t['name'] 
                        for t in json_obj['schema']['fields']])
    df = df.astype(dtype={t['name']: t['type'][:3] 
                        for t in json_obj['schema']['fields']}).set_index('index')
    df.index.name = None

print(df)
#    a  b
# 0  1  4
# 1  2  5
# 2  3  6
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. This solves most part of the question. There is only one problem left, how can I apply the fields->type to the `dtypes` of DataFrame(such as column 'a': int, columns 'b': int)? which I think is the most valuable part of 'table' orient

Comment: See update parsing json object for *dtype* and *columns* assignment.

Comment: awesome. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function I have developed from Parfait answer:

```
def table_to_df(table):
    df = pd.DataFrame(table['data'],
                      columns=[t['name'] for t in table['schema']['fields']])
    for t in table['schema']['fields']:
        if t['type'] == "datetime":
            df[t['name']] = pd.to_datetime(df[t['name']], infer_datetime_format=True)
    df.set_index(table['schema']['primaryKey'], inplace=True)
    return df
```